# Removed Module Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, uninstall-module

I have removed all files of a Module and now i have this exception:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Tiny_Compressimages_Block_Adminhtml_ApiNotification' in {{server_folder}}/app/Mage.php:595
```

What have i missed?

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to clear the cache, solved :)